# C# reading excel file where the header is not the first row

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read data from an excel file. Full code below. The first few lines are junk, so skip them using the following

```
"SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] WHERE [F3] <> ''";
```

I want to read the code to a datatable and still keep the headers. which appear after the junk lines.

The problem is that when I filter our the junk lines using the WHERE clause above, the datatable column titles come out as F1,F2 etc

In my connection string I do specify I want the headers

HDR=Yes.

If I remove the WHERE clause from the SELECT, it works as I expect.

Please advise

```
switch (Extension)
            {
                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                    conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    break;
            }
            conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "Yes");
            OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

            //Get the name of First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            DataTable dtExcelSchema;
            dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            string SheetName = ListSheets.SelectedValue;
            connExcel.Close();

            //Read Data from First Sheet
            connExcel.Open();
            cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] WHERE [F3] <> ''";
            oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
            oda.Fill(dt);


     connExcel.Close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have fixed lines of junk code in your Excel Sheet, you could execute the query like this.

```
"SELECT * From [Sheet1$A5:C]"
```

The assumption here is that your headers are on line 5 and C is the column where your data ends. This correctly loads the header names for the columns.

Adding a snapshot of the Excel against which the above query works.

[image]

Comment: Because that way the headers from excel don't get put into the data table as headers

Comment: are the no. of junk lines fixed in your sheet?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if that works for you. I have run it locally and it seems to do what you ask for.

Comment: That seems to get the headers but not the data

Comment: It does get the data too. What is the row count you get?